# Under what circumstance will kafka overflow?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am testing a POC where data will be sent from 50+ servers from UDP port to kafka client (Will use UDP-kafka bridge). Each servers generates ~2000 messages/sec and that adds up to 100K+ messages/sec for all 50+ servers. My question here is

1. What will happen if kafka is not able to ingest all those messages?
   Will that create a backlog on my 50+ servers?
2. If I have a kafka cluster, how do I decide which server sends message to which broker?

Comment: The title of your question doesn't really match the questions you're asking. In any case, Kafka topics won't overflow, because the disks will fill up and the brokers just stop

Comment: @cricket_007 - So I can keep adding disk to the system to avoid brokers failure?

Comment: It's typically better to add more brokers because adding disks requires a broker restart, I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) It depends what you mean by "not able" to ingest. If you mean it's bottlenecked by the network, then you'll likely just get timeouts when trying to produce some of your messages. If you have `retries` *([documented here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs))* set up to anything other than the default (0) then it will attempt to send the message that many times. You can also customise the `request.timeout.ms`, the default value of this being 30 seconds. If you mean in terms of disk space, the broker will probably crash.

2) You do this in a roundabout way. When you create a topic with N partitions, the brokers will create those partitions on whichever server has the least usage at that time, one by one. This means that, if you have 10 brokers, and you create a 10 partition topic, each broker should receive one partition. Now, you can specify which partition to send a message to, but you can't specify which broker that partition will be on. It's possible to find out which broker a partition is on after you have created it, so you could create a map of partitions to brokers and use that to choose which broker to send to.

Comment: 1) If I set retry to false and timeout to 5 seconds, because of the bottleneck by network, kafka producer client cannot take messages, will those message die?

Comment: The messages will not be sent, correct. They'll just be discarded.

Comment: I don't think it's guaranteed Kafka spreads partitions evenly over brokers

Comment: That's true. I believe the actual logic is that it tries to use the broker with the fewest partitions on it when creating a new partition.

Comment: What if I use small machine with huge storage and high ingestion rate?

Comment: Then it will take longer for your broker to crash due to running out of disk space.